# I could not find the part of the path when I use the Now.Adddays(-1)

Tags: vb.net

If I'm using the normal date, the program is running but when I add the `Now.AddDays(-1)` which is yesterday's date I get an error at this part:

`zip.Save(Main.temporarypath + "\" + finalname)`

The error is:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\NPSSOJT\Desktop\EHQ-BOS 4.0.1\EHQ-BOS 4.0.1\bin\Release\compressed\5\26\DotNetZip-ldqehecj.tmp'.

The DotNetZip keeps on changing everytime I run the program.

```
Shared Sub compressFile()
        Dim logfile As String = "C:\Users\" + Main.pcname + "\Desktop\EHQ-LOGS.txt"
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = AppendText(logfile)
        Dim ddformat As String = Now().AddDays(-1)
        Dim yesterday As String = ddformat
        Dim format2 As String = "hh-mm-ss"
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim filename As String = (time.ToString(format2)) + ".zip"
        Dim finalname As String = yesterday + filename
        MessageBox.Show(finalname)


        sw.WriteLine(Now() + " (Compression)" + " " + "Compressing " + finalname)
        Using zip As New ZipFile()
            zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1
            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.Level9
            zip.AddDirectory(Main.originpath, "")
            zip.Save(Main.temporarypath + "\" + finalname)
```

Comment: `+` is for math, `&` is for strings. `.AddDays` does not return a String, but rather a `Date`. What does the debug tell you about the variables?

Comment: You cannot rely on `"C:\Users\" + Main.pcname + "\Desktop` to get you the actual path to the desktop. This can be changed. Try this instead `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`.

Comment: Also, please set `Option Strict On`. You'll discover a lot more errors at compile-time rather than at run-time.

Comment: Check the content of `Main.originpath` and `Main.temporarypath` - you are not showing relevant code. Looks like it is using your bin folder. Also use `Path.Combine(Main.temporarypath, finalname)` instead of `+`.